# Convert "summed up flags" back to original meaning

Tags: sql, postgresql, flags

I have to work with a database that includes a column `change` indicating in which manner three other columns have been changed in comparision to the previous corresponding entry. The change type can be `new`, `removed` or `changed`.

These types are assigned the following numbers:

```
column    |   a       b       c
----------+----------------------
new       |   3       12      48
removed   |   2       8       32
changed   |   1       4       16
```

The `change` column's content is the sum of all applying change types, i.e. if column `a` was `changed` and `b` `removed`, the `change` column would be 1+8=9. (There is always a change, i.e. there can be 1, 2 or 3 summands.)

My problem: I can't think of a smart way to convert this "summed up flag" back to its original meaning (part of the problem being not knowing what to google for).

I can tell that if `change` is uneven, `a` was either `new` or `changed`; and that if `change>=48`, `c` was `new` plus possibly other changes, else `change>=32` => `c` was `removed` plus possibly other changes and so on. I could probably put that together into a huge logical query -- but I'm sure there must be a sophisticated solution to do this.

I use PostgreSQL in case that's relevant. The table has about 50 million rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using the bit-wise AND operator (`&`) in combination with bit-wise shifts (`>>`).

The following query returns all the table's records, with in three additional columns the change to *a*, *b*, and *c* respectively:

```
select  *,
        case change & 3 
             when 1 then 'changed'
             when 2 then 'removed'
             when 3 then 'new'
        end as change_to_a,
        case (change >> 2) & 3 
             when 1 then 'changed'
             when 2 then 'removed'
             when 3 then 'new'
        end as change_to_b,
        case (change >> 4) & 3 
             when 1 then 'changed'
             when 2 then 'removed'
             when 3 then 'new'
        end as change_to_c
from    mytable;
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9cdee/1).

Example output:

```
id  change  change_to_a change_to_b change_to_c
-----------------------------------------------
1     9       changed     removed     (null)
2    50       removed     (null)        new
3    83         new       (null)      changed
4    20        (null)     changed     changed
5    25       changed     removed     changed
```

Here is another approach. This also returns 3 additional columns, but one per type of change, and the values are a concatenation of *'a', 'b', 'c'*:

```
select  *,
        concat(
          case when change        & 3 = 1 then 'a' end,
          case when (change >> 2) & 3 = 1 then 'b' end, 
          case when (change >> 4) & 3 = 1 then 'c' end) changed,
        concat(
          case when change        & 3 = 2 then 'a' end,
          case when (change >> 2) & 3 = 2 then 'b' end, 
          case when (change >> 4) & 3 = 2 then 'c' end) removed,
        concat(
          case when change        & 3 = 3 then 'a' end,
          case when (change >> 2) & 3 = 3 then 'b' end, 
          case when (change >> 4) & 3 = 3 then 'c' end) new
from    mytable;
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9cdee/2).

Example output:

```
id  change  changed     removed    new
-----------------------------------------
1     9        a            b     (null)
2    50     (null)          a       c
3    83        c         (null)     a
4    20       bc         (null)   (null)
5    25       ac            b     (null)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works beautifully. Just HOW did you know to use `&` with 3 on each and `>>` some with 2 or 4? Try and error? Logic? It makes sense once you've got it, but getting there is the hard thing...

Comment: This is logic. As you know the numbers are multiplied by four for *b* compared to *a*, and again by four to get the *c* case. Now dividing by four is the same as shifting 2 binary digits [this is something programmers of my (old) age all know]. The AND operator is a way to extract certain bits. The number 3 corresponds to the lower 2 bits of a number, which can have value 0-3. It certainly is logic, and it helps a lot when you get to grips with the binary system, masking and shifting.

Comment: Ah ok, I get it. Young programmer here, still a lot to learn, especially on this abstract level. I've heard of bit-wise operations before, but never really got into or used them so far. Thanks again, great answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use bit operations.  If I understand correctly:

```
select (case when col::bit(8) & B'00000011' then 'new'
             when col::bit(8) & B'00000001' then 'changed'
             when col::bit(8) & B'00000010' then 'removed'
        end) as a_status,
       (case when col::bit(8) & B'00001100' then 'new'
             when col::bit(8) & B'00000100' then 'changed'
             when col::bit(8) & B'00001000' then 'removed'
        end) as b_status,
       (case when col::bit(8) & B'00110000' then 'new'
             when col::bit(8) & B'00010000' then 'changed'
             when col::bit(8) & B'00100000' then 'removed'
        end) as c_status
```

Comment: I didn't quite get yours to work... :/ Postgres doesn't want to use `&` on an integer and I couldn't properly cast `changed` to bin or find a `dectobin` function... That's a pity as I'm really curious how you solved it without bit-wise shifting like trincot did.

Comment: @user3746543 . . . If `col` is an integer, then you can convert it to a `bit()` type for the operation.